# Calculating difference between dates for different event types in pyspark

Tags: count, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to calculate the Datediff and count_diff in pyspark on an event data.

the data looks like this

```
deviceid  techid name count   load_date
m1          1     a    30    23-01-2016
m2          1     b    40    23-01-2016
m1          1     a    45    29-01-2016
m1          2     a    50    30-01-2016
```

and I want it to look like this

```
deviceid  techid name count   load_date   datediff  countdiff
m1          1     a    30    23-01-2016    NA         NA
m2          1     b    40    23-01-2016    NA         NA 
m1          1     a    45    29-01-2016    6          15
m1          2     a    50    30-01-2016    NA         NA
```

How do I create a column with these values in pyspark, taking datediff on the change of event condition.

Comment: Will there ever be more than 2 entries for the same techid-name pair? If so, what does datediff/countdiff look like in those situations? If 2 is the max, one possible solution is a) copy the df b) rename the columns of the copy c) join the df with the copy d) calculate the diffs

Comment: There will be more than 2 entries, there will be multiple. I thought of grouping the device ids , techids and name. then sorting it by load_date and introducing a new column with lag in the load_date and count as previous_load_date and previous_count and then taking the different. But I am not sure that would be the right method @David

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using windowing functions.

(1) Create Dataframe with sample test data

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('m1',1,'a',30,'23-01-2016'),('m2',1,'b',40,'23-01-2016'),('m1',1,'a',45,'29-01-2016'),('m1',2,'a',50,'30-01-2016')], ['deviceid','techid','name','count','load_date'])

df1 = df.selectExpr("deviceid","techid","name","count","to_timestamp(load_date, 'dd-MM-yyyy') AS load_date")
```

(2) Define window and build previous count and previous load date columns logic using `lag` function

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number,lag

windowSpec = Window.partitionBy('deviceid','techid').orderBy('load_date')
prev_count = lag('count').over(windowSpec).alias('rank')
prev_load_date = lag('load_date').over(windowSpec).alias('rank')

df2 = df1.withColumn("prev_count", prev_count) \
    .withColumn("prev_load_date", prev_load_date)
```

(3) Subtract  original columns with previous columns to calculate difference.

```
df2.selectExpr("deviceid",
               "techid",
               "name",
               "count",
               "load_date",
               "datediff(load_date,prev_load_date) AS datediff",
               "(count - prev_count) AS countdiff")\
    .show()

#+--------+------+----+-----+-------------------+--------+---------+
#|deviceid|techid|name|count|          load_date|datediff|countdiff|
#+--------+------+----+-----+-------------------+--------+---------+
#|      m1|     1|   a|   30|2016-01-23 00:00:00|    null|     null|
#|      m1|     1|   a|   45|2016-01-29 00:00:00|       6|       15|
#|      m1|     2|   a|   50|2016-01-30 00:00:00|    null|     null|
#|      m2|     1|   b|   40|2016-01-23 00:00:00|    null|     null|
#+--------+------+----+-----+-------------------+--------+---------+
```